# StructureMap Documentation

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, structuremap

I am new to Dependency Injection.
Does anyone have an idea about the way StructureMap works? I've been searching for a documentation for that but all I found was the API documentation (the list of Namespaces and methods), not what I want. I need an "howTo". Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1):

The place I learned it from is http://docs.structuremap.net/. If you have no prior experience with StructureMap, be sure to read the sections A Gentle Quickstart and Auto-Wiring, and you should have the basics you need to start using it.

Another nice overview I found is [this one](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Stefan-Forsberg/Dates/2010/8/An-introduction-to-StructureMap/). Incidentally, it uses the `For<...>.Use(...)` syntax which I prefer.

Also, LosTechies has a series on StructureMap, e.g. see [StructureMap: Medium-level usage scenario's](http://lostechies.com/chadmyers/2008/07/17/structuremap-medium-level-usage-scenarios/).

Comment: It looks like structuremap.net is no more. Documentation is here now: http://structuremap.github.io/documentation/